# How do I pass an EnumMap to a function?

Tags: rust, enums, hashmap, enum-map

**Goal:**
To pass an EnumMap from the enum_map crate to a function

**My error:**

`25  | fn print_board(board: &[CellStatus], celldict: & EnumMap<&CellStatus, &str>){`
|                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `EnumArray<&str>` is not implemented for `&CellStatus`

**Relevant code:**

```
use enum_map::{enum_map, EnumMap};

enum CellStatus{
    Empty,
    Cross,
    Circle,
}

fn print_board(board: &[CellStatus], celldict: & EnumMap<&CellStatus, &str>){
    for cell in board {
        println!("{}", celldict[cell]);

    }
}



fn main() {


    let cell_repr = enum_map! {
        CellStatus::Empty  => " _ ".to_string(),
        CellStatus::Cross  => " X ".to_string(),
        CellStatus::Circle => " O ".to_string(),
    };


}
```

**Background:**

Im trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe game as my first rust script. I havent implemented the logic yet of the game. I could make it work by just passing integers and a bunch of if statements but i wanted to write it in a more clean way.

Im guessing I have to implement something for my enum? but im not sure how to go about doing that.

Full code: https://pastebin.com/pZwqyvR2
Crate in question: https://docs.rs/enum-map/latest/enum_map/#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the documentation you posted, you have to `derive` the crate's trait in order to use `enum_map!` on that `enum`. The only modification is just before your `enum` definition:

```rust
#[derive(Enum)]
enum CellStatus {
  Empty,
  Cross,
  Circle,
}
```

Also, the result of `enum_map!` is a `EnumMap<CellStatus, String>` in your case, not a `EnumMap<&CellStatus, &str>`, Changing into that type should help. It complains that `&CellStatus` does not implement a certain trait because that trait is automatically implemented by the derive macro for `CellStatus`, and not for `&CellStatus`. However, if you do this it will still not compile, because `EnumMap` does not implement `Index<&CellStatus>`, but only `Index<CellStatus>` (which is a bit stupid if you ask me). Anyways, the best way to patch this IMO is to make `CellStatus` `Copy`. The following compiles:

```rust
use enum_map::{enum_map, Enum, EnumMap};

#[derive(Enum, Clone, Copy)]
enum CellStatus {
    Empty,
    Cross,
    Circle,
}

fn print_board(board: &[CellStatus], celldict: &EnumMap<CellStatus, String>){
    for cell in board {
        println!("{}", celldict[*cell]);

    }
}

fn main() {
    let cell_repr = enum_map! {
        CellStatus::Empty => String::from("_"),
        CellStatus::Cross => String::from("X"),
        CellStatus::Circle => String::from("O"),
    };
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt seem to do anything, heres the error msg: https://pastebin.com/fyuYAXBu 
  
from this code: https://pastebin.com/Y3hg1v8V

Comment: @Tor edited the answer to provide a code snippet that does compile.

Comment: That works now, thanks a lot! Ill make sure to look more into the derive feature